# Matching content inside a tag

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

I need to parse some string from an input file. These string are needed in Hadoop.
The problem is, these string are in markup tags.

Can someone suggest me a pattern, to match and store them

```
<id>INIcE89C561</id>  <id>INIcE89C560</id>  <id>Q1S5WLipQW2</id>
```

I need the string between id tag. All the tags are from different input file.
I need to use them as a Value. In key value pair.

Comment: That looks an awful lot like xml, is that the case for the entire input file?

Comment: some of the sample input is lile  arabia ||INIcE89C560||INIcE89C561
area ||Q1S5WLipQW2
asics ||Q1S5WLipQW2  <record>
<id>INIcE89C561</id>
<cv_text>INIcE89C56  
at ||Q1S5WLipQW2
badminton ||Q1S5WLipQW2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the text between the id tag you can use something like:

```
<id>([^<]*)</id>
```

And then extract the first captured group (which is your value).

In general, however, regex is not the best option for parsing XML.

There are much better suited XML parsers, that I recommend using.

Take a look at [this](http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/java-xml-tutorials/) tutorial for example.

Comment: Naa . This looks fine for me. The id tag in only in one line and that is only requried once.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using something like so: `<id>(.*?)</id>`. This should match all the characters between the `<id>` and `</id>` tags. The problem though might be that the groups of text which the regex captures will most likely be overwritten by the next group of text that the regex captures, meaning that by the end of the day, you will only have the last group of matching text.

What I would recommend you do is to first split these by white space characters (assuming that you are getting the same text that you have posted as an example) and then apply the regex on the individual blocks. Also, if there are more tags than this, I would recommend you use some other way of extracting your information since regex's where not exactly designed to extract information from markup languages.